# $.each not able to obtain attribute of element

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var times = [];
$.each(".time", function() {
    times.push($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

The code above is returning `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '14' in .time`

Any ideas why? I could have sworn I've used the same syntax before and it's worked just fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you want `$(".time")`, not `".time"`. That is, you want to iterate through all of the elements with class `time`. Otherwise you would be iterating through the characters in the string: `['.', 't', 'i', 'm', 'e']`.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: No, it's the answer.

Comment: @bjb568 It answers my question so why is it not an answer? Just because it's a simple fix doesn't mean it should be a comment

Comment: It's a duplicate though

Comment: @jskidd3 An answer needs more than how to do it. It needs to explain how, why, and what didn't work in the original code.

Comment: @bjb568 Ok lol, well the last time I checked the answer is the answer in programming, no need for an essay :-)

Comment: @jskidd3 to be fair though, an explanation would be helpful to minimize the chance of the same mistake (or similar mistakes) being made in the future.

Comment: @jskidd3 false. Code dump answers are terrible answers. A good answer is explained, no matter how trivial.

Comment: Okie dokie no problemo, thanks @JoeFrambach for your answer :-)

Comment: @jskidd3 [Read the question carefully. What, specifically, is the question asking for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) Well, it asked "Any ideas why?".

Comment: @bjb568 Bring it up on meta, the comments on an answer are not the place to discuss meta.

Comment: @Joe It has been brought up many times before, and the consensus is code-dump answers are unacceptable. In any case, we have already reached an agreement here, and the answer has been edited. If you want, you could mod-flag this for comment cleanup.

Comment: If there was a timestamp of when my edit occurred, you'd see my final answer before your first comment occurred. This is a FGITW problem, not a code-dump problem.

Comment: Then it is a bad answer that shows you are not willing to cast a duplicate vote over getting 100 rep.

Answer (score 6):

`$.each` doesn't accept string selectors, only objects and arrays, so it's either

```
$('.time').each(function() {...
```

or

```
$.each($(".time"), function() {...
```

where the latter gets an object from `$('.time')`